# widget="float" for char field

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo

I have problem in alignment of tree view column so I change my field from "`float`" to "`char`" type and giving `widget="float"` to accept only number or float or integer values.
I declared in `.py` file

```
"demo1_field_char":fields.char("Test char field for Int", size = 64)
```

and in .xml file

```
< field name="demo1_field_char" widget="float" />
```

I got error while I am saving record and error is as follow:

```
Uncaught Error: [_.sprintf] expecting number but found string
```

but it validate for float or integer values that means if I put char in that field that gives right notification. Problem is in save only.

Thank you in Advance.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is because you are using `widget=float` in `char` field. Try it again after removing `widget=float`.

Comment: But Arya, I wanted to accept only integer or float value.and If i take float or integer fields then that gives problem in alignment in tree view.